# QSerialPort in a thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, serial-port

this is my first ever Q on stackoverflow, so please bear with me.

I have a Virtual Serial Port USB device that I communicate with using QSerialPort (Qt-5.9). There is a lot of data that needs to be sent to it (around 6 KB every 40ms) and a fair bit to read as well. The device sends data every few milliseconds.

On a Mac, I cannot just dump all the write data as it seems to overflow Mac's internal write buffers. If this happens, there is no indication, and subsequent writes will fail forever. A solution is to flush() after each write. Windows and Linux are fine with accepting large amounts of write data, as long as there is enough time to pipe data in/out before the new lot needs to be sent or received. In other words, on Windows and Linux, communication does not need to be blocking, but problems described below still exist.

If I access the port from the main thread, all is good. It runs like a charm. But, with flush() writes are now blocking. They take time. My application needs to be able to communicate to one or more of these devices at a time. In this scenario GUI thread suffers.

So a solution is to move serial port accesses to a thread. This is where fun starts. I tried this:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////
Device::Device  (const QString portName):
    QThread     (nullptr),
    mSerPort    (nullptr),
    mPortPath   (portName)
{
}

//////////////////////////////////////////
bool Device::StartThread (void)
{
    // Create and open serial port
    mSerPort = new QSerialPort(mPortPath);
    mSerPort->moveToThread(this);
    mSerPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    if (mSerPort->isOpen() == false)
    {
        qDebug() << mSerPort->errorString();
    }
    // Start thread (execute run())
    start();
}

//////////////////////////////////////////
void Device::run (void)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (mSerPort->isOpen() == true)
        {
            Read();       // Read data from the device
//          Write();      // Write data to the device
        }
        msleep(THREAD_SLEEP_MS);
    }
}
```

Read() and Write() are just thin wrappers around QSerialPort's read() and write() functions. There is no data sharing with other threads.

In this scenario, I get a runtime warning on port open():

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QSerialPort(0x109676430), parent's thread is Device(0x10400b0a0), current thread is QThread(0x101503cb0)
```

which is understandable, since Device::StartThread() is called from the GUI thread. However, the application runs fine for a while, reading (and writing if Write() is not commented out) but then eventually crashes with access violation inside QSerialPort::read().

So, my next attempt is to move port open() to run():

```
//////////////////////////////////////////
void Device::run (void)
{
    // Open the serial port
    mSerPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    if (mSerPort->isOpen() == false)
    {
        qDebug() << mSerPort->errorString();
        return;
    }
    while (true)
    {
    ...
```

This ensures that the port is completely inside the Device thread. Unfortunately, in this scenario, Read() never gets any data from the port. All reads return 0 bytes. No port errors are reported.

What am I doing wrong? Why is there no data read from the device (I am positive, data is there to be read)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're not completely moving the `QSerialPort` to the thread to use it properly.  Check out this guide on how to properly create threads from the Qt documentation: https://wiki.qt.io/QThreads_general_usage

The important part to know is that a lot of old guides tell you to override the `run` method in a `QThread` - don't do that!  I can't tell from the code that you've posted  if you're inheriting from `QThread`.

If you do have a separate thread for the serial communications, you should also be able to go to an event-driven system, using a `QTimer` to periodically send the messages that you have to send to your device.

Comment: Yes, Device was a sub-class of QThread, and was trying to interrogate my port from run(). I now changed it to QObject derived class, implemented timerEvent(), moved it to a separate QThread object. Everything works now. Thank you